# How to make textview inside a content layout with collapsing toolbar scroll

Tags: android, textview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a `TextView` which is inside a certain layout. This layout's header layout has a collapsing toolbar. So the collapsing toolbar is the main layout and its content layout has a `TextView` inside it. However the content of the TextView is alot and gets cropped out when the CollapsingToolbar collapses. How do I make the TextView scrollable? The TextView I want to make scrollable is called `txtEventDescription`. My content xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Price"
    android:id="@+id/txtEventPrice"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
     />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Date"
    android:id="@+id/txtEventDate"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Event Description"
    android:id="@+id/txtEventDescription"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtEventPrice"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just encapsulate the last text view within a ScrollView layout controller.  Constrain the ScrollView height and position as you want it, then contain the text inside of it.  I used your xml to make an example:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtEventPrice"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtEventDescription"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Event Description  a big long list of event description things  a really really long list that takes up three lines"
        android:id="@+id/txtEventDescription"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: works perfectly just have to adjust layout_height accordingly